# Unhandled promise rejection error: "request failed with status code 400"

Tags: mongodb, http, mongoose, axios

I'm so baffled right now. I don't understand why I'm getting this error. The cause of this problem is mainly the bidder variable. When it's a number, there's no problem. But as soon as I set it as a string, it throws the 400 error. This is my schema for my collection.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var TransactionSchema = new Schema({
  saleNumber: Number,
  bidder: String,
  purchaseAmount: Number,
  purchaseType: String
},{
    collection: 'Transaction'
});

var Transaction = mongoose.model('Transaction', TransactionSchema);
module.exports = Transaction;
```

And in this function, I'm trying to add a document to my collection.

```
async addNewTransaction() {
  let newTransaction = {
    saleNumber: this.saleNumber,
    bidder: this.bidder,
    purchaseAmount: this.purchaseAmount,
    purchaseType: this.purchaseType
  }
  let uri = `http://${process.env.HOST_NAME}:8081/transaction/add`
  await this.axios.post(uri, newTransaction).then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
  })
},
```

And this is my route for adding a new document:

```
// Add a transaction
transactionRoutes.route('/add').post(function (req, res) {
  var transaction = new Transaction(req.body)
  if (transaction.saleNumber && transaction.bidder) {
    transaction.save()
    .then(transaction => {
      res.status(200).json({'transaction': 'transaction added successfully'})
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).send("unable to save to database")
    })
  }
})
```

**Update**
Deleted the whole collection and started a new one, which solved my problem!

Comment: Add `console.log(err)` in `catch` and you'll see what error is.

Comment: Just a tip, but I think this .catch looks a bit cleaner:

.catch((error) => res.status(400).json(error))

I don't know if its any better than yours, but it will return the error so it will be clearer what the problem is.